# Matlab / Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express: What is "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol"?

Tags: visual-c++, matlab

I am trying to create a simple C++ class and a Matlab mex file.  My code is as follows:

Matlab: mexTest1.cpp

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "K:\\My Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\HelloWorld\\HelloWorld\\Class1.h"

/* Input Arguments */
#define X   prhs[0]

/* Output Arguments */
#define RESULT  plhs[0]

void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], 
          int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] ){ 
    /* Initialize input and output pointers
    // Inputs */
    double *x; 
    /* Outputs */
    double r;
    double *result; 

    mwSize m,n; 

    m = mxGetM(X); 
    n = mxGetN(X); 

    /* Create a matrix for the return argument */ 
    RESULT = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
    /* Assign pointers to the various parameters */ 
    result = mxGetPr(RESULT);

    x = mxGetPr(X);

    /* Do the actual computations in a subroutine */
    Class1 c1(2, 15.0);
    r = c1.product();

    result[0] = r;
    return;

}
```

Class1.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <string> // Standard string class in C++

class Class1
{
public:
    int a;
    double b;
public:
    Class1(const int& a, const double& b);
    //virtual ~Class1();
    void print() const;
    double product() const;
};
```

Class1.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Class1.h"

Class1::Class1(const int& a, const double& b){
    Class1::a = a;
    Class1::b = b;
}

void Class1::print() const{
    std::cout << "a=" << Class1::a << " * b=" << Class1::b << " = " << Class1::product() << std::endl;
}

double Class1::product() const{
    return a*b;
}
```

Running the Matlab command `mex mexTest1.cpp` gives the error messages:

```
Creating library C:\DOCUME~1\K\LOCALS~1\TEMP\MEX_RH~1\templib.x and object C:\DOCUME~1\K\LOCALS~1\TEMP\MEX_RH~1\templib.exp 
mexTest1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: double __thiscall Class1::product(void)const " (?product@Class1@@QBENXZ) referenced in function _mexFunction 
mexTest1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Class1::Class1(int const &,double const &)" (??0Class1@@QAE@ABHABN@Z) referenced in function _mexFunction 
mexTest1.mexw32 : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals 

  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2011A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Link of 'mexTest1.mexw32' failed. 

??? Error using ==> mex at 208
Unable to complete successfully.
```

Can anyone help me fix this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linker is telling you that in trying to construct an executable, it wasn't supplied with an object file that contains `Class1::product` and `Class1::Class1`. That's because those functions would be supplied by compiling `Class1.cpp`, which your command line doesn't ask for.

You should use the [syntax of `mex` for multiple files](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1600/1605.html#linking_multiple): `mex mexTest1.cpp Class1.cpp`

Comment: Is there a way to have Class1.cpp automatically compiled (or pre-compiled) and linked from within the mexTest1.cpp file (which would be esp. usefule if I have lots of Class files to include)?

Answer (score 2):

Your linker is unable to find deinitions(bodies) Class1 methods (constructor and product). This may be due to

1. You haven't provided any definition(body)
2. The definitions are in a lib file which you forgot to link to